rust-analyzer failed due to namespaced features with the dep
I'm a noob with rust and I'm playing with optional dependencies and I'm getting this error:


namespaced features with the dep: prefix are only allowed on the nightly channel and requires the -Z namespaced-features flag on the command-line

This is my Cargo.toml:
[package]
name = "cargo_features"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"], optional = true }
rgb = { version = "0.8.25", features = ["serde"], optional = true }

# we can add optional features we need to put the key "optional dependencies" as true
[features]
# features are disabled by default, but we can enable them by default
color = ["dep:rgb"]

Thanks!

dep: was stabilized in Rust 1.60. Are you using a version older than that?

[ cargo_features ]$ rustc --version rustc 1.78.0 (9b00956e5 2024-04-29)

Check if the Cargo rust-analyzer uses is the same as in rustc --version.

@ChayimFriedman $ rustup component add rust-analyzer info: downloading component 'rust-analyzer' info: installing component 'rust-analyzer'
And this is the rust-analyzer version:
[ lets_get_rusty ]$ rust-analyzer --version rust-analyzer 1.78.0 (9b00956 2024-04-29)

If you're using VSCode, it downloads its own rust-analyzer. Also, the version of cargo rust-analyzer uses is determined by its settings.
